# Highlight column of grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, grid

i need to highlight a column of a grid when clicked for sorting.

Comment: And what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please don't put things like "asp.net c#" in the title. Please just use the tags for that sort of thing.